# $ f'=0 \iff f \, \text{is Constant} $

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

> Mark true or false. Justify your answers.
>   $$ f'=0  \text{ if and only if }  f\,\text{is Constant} $$

**My Proof**
in my proof i choose domain $$f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$$

- First we show that $f$ must be constant in $(a;b)$:
  Suppose not, there $\exists\quad  x<y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$:
  Without loss of generality, we assume $f(x)<f(y)$; it follows from the Mean Value Theorem that $\exists\, c \in (x;y)$ such that
  $$f'(c)=\dfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\neq 0;$$
  a contradiction.
  Next we want to prove that $f(a)=f(b)=$constant too.

Since $f$ is continuous at $x=a$; we take any sequence $\{x_n\}\cap (a;b)\to a$; we have $f(a)=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty }f(x_n)=\text{constant}$.
Similarly, $f(b)$ should be the same constant too.

- Conversely

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} -1& x < 0\\1 & x \geq 0\end{cases} $$

since $\lim_{x\to 0-}f(x)=-1\neq \lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)=1=f(0)$ then $f$ isn't continuous then not differential at $0$

- Is my proof correct
- if the domains are chosen to be connex can we have equivalent

Comment: To define $f'$, you should assume $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ or something like that.

Comment: Any constant function $f$ whose domain is discontinuous can work as counterexample.

Comment: Your question is missing quite some context. Is the domain of $f$ an open interval $(a,b)$? If so, then it's not defined neither at $a$ nor $b$. Does $f'=0$ applies to the whole domain? That is, do you have $f'\equiv 0$ or is it $f'=0$? If the latter, then it is false; if the former, then apply simply the definition of derivative to show it is constant. Your way, by contradiction is ok, but your wording is messy.

Comment: @Asydot: What do you mean ? the domain is $[a,b]$ !

Comment: @idm In OP's original version it just said "$f'=0$ if and only if $f$ is constant" and the condition was not there.

Comment: Have you *chosen* your domain as $[a,b]$, or is $f$ originally defined there? Because there are non-constant differentiable functions on non-connected domains that have a vanishing derivative...

Comment: if i choose connex domain can we confirm the equivalent